# what is har-validator and how can i resolve this

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

```bash
C:\Users\21vde>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\21vde\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\.bin\uuid.ps1
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\21vde\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\.bin\uuid.ps1: is outside C:\Users\21vde\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\uuid and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\21vde\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\.bin\uuid.ps1
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Angular team](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/20337), it is solved in Angular 12.

You can find more details in this [Angular GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16952).

Comment: Well i am in angular 14 version and still issue exists.

Comment: Same problem here. I also migrated from TSLint to ESLint. Still same issue.